# How to Mount a file from Host to Container via Docker-Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Any I missing something simple here. But Im trying to mount a host file to the container via docker-compose. My docker-compose.yml is:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
    myapp_poller:
        restart: unless-stopped
        image: &myappImage netenglabs/myapp:0.13.0
        container_name: myapp_poller
        command: -D /myapp/inventory.yml -k
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
        volumes:
            - "parquet-db:/myapp/parquet"
            - "./config/inventory.yml:/myapp/inventory.yml"
            - "./config/myapp-cfg.yml:/root/.myapp/myapp-cfg.yml"
        entrypoint:
            - sq-poller
```

If I go into `./config` and run `docker-compose up -d` I get:

```
ERROR: for myapp_poller  Cannot start service myapp_poller: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:495: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:60: mounting "/run/desktop/mnt/host/wsl/docker-desktop-bind-mounts/Ubuntu-20.04/cc227aed2745c686a488b2a5b99142480733c23c6aa9f72f7d7cb77b4506cee2" to rootfs at "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8b2cfc582829f784a1a918ba17ef667d2d4c4291b9c0d6655f6f813da486e333/merged/root/.myapp/myapp-cfg.yml" caused: not a directory: unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
```

Thanks,

Comment: Does the file `./config/myapp-cfg.yml` exist, on your host, relative to the directory containing the `docker-compose.yml` file?  If you `cd config; docker-compose up` that's looking for a `./config/config` subdirectory.

Comment: Its strange I rebooted and restarted all services and its now working as expected.